# Updating Model from Console in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes, console

I looked around and this seems simple but I can't find the answer.
I'm very new at RoR (as in just started learning today) so let me know if my terminology is wrong!

How do I modify a model's attributes from the RoR console?

Where I am:

- created new app
- created new controller ($ rails generate controller textbooks)
- added routing (added "resources :textbooks" to routes.rb)
- created model with one attribute ($ rails generate model textbook title:string)
- Added to DB ($ rake db:migrate)

How do I add a new attribute from the console?

Comment: google didn't help? just use `$ rails generate migration add_color_to_baloons color:string`. I assume here your table is named `ballons`. google *rails migrations* for more info

Comment: Awesome. Seemed. to work. Didn't show up in the app>models>textbook.rb file though. Should it, or does this just create it in the DB?

Comment: No , you have changed db scheme  , not the model . Your change is at the migration file in db/migrate .

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you are almost there :)
Now you should start the rails console : on your projects dir just type :

```
rails c
```

(c is for console)

Then you type :

```
first_textbook = Textbook.new(:name => "My first textbook")
```

and then

```
first_textbook.save
```

Comment: he wants to add a new attribute , haha

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I'm trying to update the database and model to have a new row in the table, not update an individual entry. Does that make sense? Haha. I'm not quite sure how to word this.

Comment: It seems I did not understand your question correctly  , sorry . @shime 's comment is most valuable in you case.

Comment: But I think you mean you'd like to add a new column , not a new row , in your database . Column is an attribute , row is a new record in db.